# Will Ubuntu use my full RAM in dual boot?

Tags: dual-boot, windows, virtualization, ram

When I run Ubuntu in dual boot will I still be able to use my full 4 GB RAM if I am not running Win 7 at the same time?

Answer (score 3):

In Dualboot mode you can only run one operating system at a time. So the running Operating system will get full resources, whether its ram , cpu, hdd etc.

Read more here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-booting

If you want to use multiple os simultaniously you can use virtualization software like Virtualbox or Vmware etc. These software will allow you to run/emulate many Operating systems inside your Base operating system

- VirtualBox : https://www.virtualbox.org/
- vmware player: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VMware_Player